# terraform import not working when terraform code has resource blocks which create resources dynamically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, import, terraform

I need solution for the below scenario, I have manually created an infra setup and now I have created terraform code for the same. I'm trying to bring that infrastructure into terraform using terraform import

So when I wrote the terraform code I used for_each in couple of places to avoid duplication of code such as creating same notification triggers for multiple buckets, adding multiple IAM roles to singe service account etc

The problem is when I run terraform import for those blocks (i.e notification triggers for multiple buckets) it's unable to import state for those notification triggers

I can change the code and map each resource to it's own resource address but number of buckets vary from environment to environment which means I need to change code for every environment How can we solve this issue?

Below is the resource block

```
resource "google_storage_notification" "test_bucket_2_notif" {
  for_each        = toset(var.test_buckets)
  bucket          = each.key
  payload_format  = "JSON_API_V1"
  topic           = google_pubsub_topic.test_pubsub_topic.id
  event_types     = ["OBJECT_FINALIZE", "OBJECT_DELETE"]
  depends_on      = [google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding.test_pubsub_role_binding]
}
```

terraform import command I used
`terraform import google_storage_notification.test_bucket_2_notif test-bucket-2/notificationConfigs/1`

I'm expecting if there is any solution using terraform state or other cli which can workaround this issue, once I get the state I don't think I will face this issue again

Answer (score 2):

Your resource declaration has a `for_each`, so there will be a map of resources created. To reference an individual resource in that map of resources (like you have to do when you `import` one of them) you have to use Terraform map notation. The notation you would use to reference each resource would be something like:

`google_storage_notification.test_bucket_2_notif["test-bucket-2"]`

Note the part in `[]` that you are completely missing in your `terraform import` statement. Before running `terraform import` you should first run `terraform plan` to see what resources Terraform thinks it needs to create, including the exact resource names Terraform is using for those resources. Then you can simply copy/paste those resource names out of the `plan` output, and into your `import` statements.

Here is [the official documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances) on referencing instances of resources created by `for_each`.